# user input initialized array example and implicit conversion

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

Is there a way to cast the unhandled exception line so that the "Input string" will be in the "correct" int "format"? I don't remember the work around for this type of incompatible implicit conversion...unhandled exception at statement in first for loop.

```
public class ArrayTest
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // initialize array
            int[] myArray;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter size of an Array");
            int arrayVariable = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            myArray = new int[arrayVariable];
            Console.WriteLine("Element at index {0}", arrayVariable);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter elements of Array");
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayVariable; i++)
            {
                myArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayVariable; i++)// Display Array Elements
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element at index {0} {1}: ", i, myArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Very unclear what you're asking. Which is the "unhandled exception line"? What kind of "cast" are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TryParse` is one of choices to validate the inut type.

```
public class ArrayTest
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // initialize array
        int[] myArray;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter size of an Array");
        int arrayVariable = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        myArray = new int[arrayVariable];
        Console.WriteLine("Element at index {0}", arrayVariable);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter elements of Array");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayVariable; i++)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine(); 
            int result;
            if(int.TryParse(input, out result))
            {
                myArray[i] = result;
            }  
            else 
            {
                 i--;
                 Console.WriteLine("Invalid input format");  
            } 
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayVariable; i++)// Display Array Elements
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element at index {0} {1}: ", i, myArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IO7lsr)

Answer (score 0):

Int32.TryParse(string, out int) method converts the specified string representation of 32-bit signed integer equivalent to out variable, and returns true if it is parsed successfully, false otherwise. This method is available in C# 2.0 and above. When s is a null reference, it will return 0 rather than throw ArgumentNullException. If s is other than an integer value, the out variable will have 0 rather than FormatException. When s represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue, the out variable will have 0 rather than OverflowException.

```
 success = Int32.TryParse(s1, out result); //-- success => true; result => 1234 
 success = Int32.TryParse(s2, out result); //-- success => false; result => 0 
 success = Int32.TryParse(s3, out result); //-- success => false; result => 0 
 success = Int32.TryParse(s4, out result); //-- success => false; result => 0
```

Convert.ToInt32 is better than Int32.Parse since it returns 0 rather than an exception. But again, according to the requirement, this can be used. TryParse will be the best since it always handles exceptions by itself.

Comment: I think you meant `Int32.TryParse`, not `Int32.Parse`. Also, it is not "available in C# 2.0"; it is available in .NET 2.0, which is not the same thing.

Comment: Ok, but you still say "C# 2.0" when it has nothing to do with C#.